# Parallel computation of NDSolve and a problem

Tags: differential-equations, parallelization

I used this code to solve a system of differential equations:

```
    ro[t_] := 
    Table[Subscript[ρ, i, j][t], {i, 1, sysdim}, {j, 1, sysdim}];

    RHS = A matrix;
    RHS2 = RHS

    ParallelTable[Flatten[NDSolve[{ro'[t] == RHS, ro[0] == initial}, Flatten[ro[t]], 
                          {t, 0, 10}]], {γ, 1, 2}]
```

Whenever I use `RHS`inside the `NDSolve`, I get this error:

> ```
>    NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`.
> ```

But, when I use `RHS2` which is basically `RHS`, I don't get any error message.

Does anybody know the problem?

---

#### Edit.

Here I put the whole code:

```
    δ[i_, j_] := KroneckerDelta[i, j]
    sysdim = 7;

    Hsystem[dimension_] := Module[{sysdim = dimension},
    V[ii_, jj_] := Module[{i = ii, j = jj}, 
        If[i > j, Return[Subscript[V, j, i]], Return[Subscript[V, i, j]]]];

    hsys[i_, j_] := δ[i, j]*Subscript[ϵ, i] + V[i, j] (1 - δ[i, j]);

    MHsys = Table[hsys[i, j], {i, 1, sysdim}, {j, 1, sysdim}]
    ]

    Hsys = Hsystem[sysdim];

    A[m_] := Table[δ[i, m]*δ[j, m], {i, 1, sysdim}, {j, 1, 
    sysdim}]
    ro[t_] := 
    Table[Subscript[ρ, i, j][t], {i, 1, sysdim}, {j, 1, sysdim}];
    (*LL=Table[(-1+δ[i,j])*ro[t][[i,j]],{i,1,sysdim},{j,1,sysdim}]*)


    L = γ*
    Sum[A[m].ro[t].A[m]\[ConjugateTranspose] - 
     1/2 (A[m].A[m]\[ConjugateTranspose].ro[t] + 
        ro[t].A[m].A[m]\[ConjugateTranspose]), {m, 1, sysdim}];

    Hrecom = Table[-I*ℏ*Γ*δ[i, j], {i, 1, 
    sysdim}, {j, 1, sysdim}];

    Htrap = Table[-I*ℏ*κ*δ[i, 3]*δ[j, 3], {i, 
    1, sysdim}, {j, 1, sysdim}];

    Hdiss = Hrecom + Htrap;

    RHS = -I/ℏ (Hsys.ro[t] - ro[t].Hsys) + -I/ℏ (Hdiss.ro[t] +
       ro[t].Hdiss) + L ;

    hcp = 6.62606957*10^-34*3*10^10*10^-12; Subscript[ϵ, 1] = 
    280*hcp; Subscript[ϵ, 2] = 
    420*hcp; Subscript[ϵ, 3] = 0; Subscript[ϵ, 4] = 
    175*hcp; Subscript[ϵ, 5] = 
    320*hcp; Subscript[ϵ, 6] = 
    360*hcp; Subscript[ϵ, 7] = 260*hcp;

    Subscript[V, 1, 2] = -106*hcp; Subscript[V, 1, 3] = 
     8*hcp; Subscript[V, 1, 4] = -5*hcp; Subscript[V, 1, 5] = 
     6*hcp; Subscript[V, 1, 6] = -8*hcp; Subscript[V, 1, 7] = -4*
     hcp;  Subscript[V, 2, 3] = 28*hcp; Subscript[V, 2, 4] = 
     6*hcp; Subscript[V, 2, 5] = 2*hcp; Subscript[V, 2, 6] = 
     13*hcp; Subscript[V, 2, 7] = 
     1*hcp; Subscript[V, 3, 4] = -62*hcp; Subscript[V, 3, 5] = -1*
     hcp; Subscript[V, 3, 6] = -9*hcp; Subscript[V, 3, 7] = 
     17*hcp; Subscript[V, 4, 5] = -70*hcp; Subscript[V, 4, 6] = -19*
     hcp; Subscript[V, 4, 7] = -57*hcp; Subscript[V, 5, 6] = 
    40*hcp; Subscript[V, 5, 7] = -2*hcp; Subscript[V, 6, 7] = 32*hcp;


    κ = 1;
    Γ = 10^-3;
    ℏ = (6.62606957*10^-34)/(2*Pi);
    initial = Table[δ[i, 6]*δ[j, 6] + δ[i, 1]*δ[j, 
      1], {i, 1, sysdim}, {j, 1, sysdim}];

    RHS2 = RHS;

    num = 20;
    upper\[TripleDot]limit = 10;
    sol = ParallelTable[NDSolve[{ro'[t] == RHS, ro[0] == initial}, Flatten[ro[t]], 
    {t, 0,upper\[TripleDot]limit}, MaxSteps -> 10^5], {γ, 1, num, 1}];//AbsoluteTiming

    dens = Flatten[Table[ro[t] /. sol[[i, All, All]], {i, 1, num}],1];
```

Comment: Where's the definition of `sysdim` and `A` and `matrix`?

Comment: sysdim is just a number. Buy `A Matrix` I meant that `RHS` is a matrix. I thought it would make the question simpler. I will upload all the code soon.

Comment: @ Kuba. How did you enter the greek letters? Using LaTex?

Comment: No, using this [addon](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1044/5478). P.s. do not put space after @.

Comment: It works just fine when you use `Table`, rather than `ParallelTable`. If you really need to parallelize this code, you'll probably need to take a close look at techniques for [resource sharing](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ResourceSharingInParallelComputing.html).

Comment: @ Mark McClure. But, why does it work with `ParallelTable` when I use `RHS2 = RHS`?

Comment: Where did you put your `RHS2=RHS`? just behind the definition of `RHS` or, just in front of the `AbsoluteTiming[……]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14723/1871

Comment: I edited the code. I put `RHS2=RHS` before solving the equation and after definition of `RHS` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to write this answer because the equivalence of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14723/1871) and the OP's question may be not immediately obvious. In short, though I'm not sure if it should be called a bug or side-effect, the culprit is the `Subscript` inside `RHS`.

I suggest not to use `Subscript`. `List` or something like `v[1, 1]` are more convenient. Personally I think `Subscript` is a compromise to the traditional form of math symbol and a somewhat pathological object in *Mathematica* which will easily trigger problems <strike>and look ugly when pasting here</strike>. There are many posts on this site about the side-effects of `Subscript`, which you can find by searching. Now let me focus on your problem.

First of all, I'd like to point out that `RHS` and `RHS2` aren't the same. Just remove the semicolon after the definition of `RHS` and `RHS2` and run your code, you'll see the differences:

***RHS*:**

[image]

***RHS2:***

[image]

Why do the differences cause an error? To make this answer cleaner I'll use a much simpler sample reproducing your problem (btw, next time you ask a question please put in some effort to reduce your problem into a minimal, workable example to attract more attention and upvotes):

```
Clear[Subscript]
eqn = y'[x] == Sin[x] + Subscript[a, 1];
Subscript[a, 1] = 1;
ParallelTable[NDSolve[{eqn, y[0] == i}, y, {x, 0, 1}], {i, 1}]
```

> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 0.`.

Removing `Subscript`, the problem doesn't exist anymore:

```
Clear[subscript]
eqn = y'[x] == Sin[x] + subscript[a, 1];
subscript[a, 1] = 1;
ParallelTable[NDSolve[{eqn, y[0] == i}, y, {x, 0, 1}], {i, 1}]
(* This works well. *)
```

Btw, any symbol that doesn't belong to the  `` Global` `` context suffers the same problem:

```
Clear["a`*"]
eqn = y'[x] == Sin[x] + a`a;
a`a = 1;
ParallelTable[NDSolve[{eqn, y[0] == i}, y, {x, 0, 1}], {i, 1}]
```

> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 0.`.

But in this case the problem can be fixed by the `DistributedContexts` option:

```
Clear["a`*"]
eqn = y'[x] == Sin[x] + a`a;
a`a = 1;
ParallelTable[NDSolve[{eqn, y[0] == i}, y, {x, 0, 1}], {i, 1}, DistributedContexts -> All]
(* This also works well. *)
```

While this won't work on `Subscript`:

```
Clear[Subscript]
eqn = y'[x] == Sin[x] + Subscript[a, 1];
Subscript[a, 1] = 1;
ParallelTable[NDSolve[{eqn, y[0] == i}, y, {x, 0, 1}], {i, 1}, DistributedContexts -> All]
```

> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 0.`.

It seems that `DistributedContexts` option can't distribute `` System` ``. Similar options or functions like `DistributeDefinitions` etc. don't work either. As I said above, I'm not sure if it's a bug or side-effect i.e. these functions are designed to work like this. Anyway, if you abandon those `Subscript`s in your code, the problem will disappear.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You are right the problem is using subscript, which is really convenient. I put the assignment of the variables of `RHS` after it, and when you execute those assignments, after that `RHS`and `RHS2` are the same. I used the subscripts again but I moved the assignment of the variables of `RHS`to before the definition of `RHS`. Now, if I use `RHS`to solve the differential equations, there won't be any problem.

Comment: It seems `ParallelTable`have some problems with subscript and there is not any problem with subscript and `Table`, however, it's not clear to me why. If the assignments are after the definition of `RHS`, it doesn't have any variable anymore(except for gama which a table is made by it). So, the question is that why can't `ParallelTable` see that there is an assignment? and how does assigning `RHS`to another variable resolve this issue?

Comment: @yashar It's because `ParallelTable` has the attribute `HoldAll`, so those `Subscript`s are passed into it before changing into numeric values. When you use `RHS2` to store `RHS`, evaluation happens, and `Subscript`s are removed, it's equivalent to use `Evaluate@RHS` inside `ParallelTable`.